# Deploy webapp project on tomcat instead of glassfish in Netbeans

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, deployment, glassfish

I have been trying to deploy my project on a Tomcat server but I keep getting this message on Netbeans

> Could not start GlassFish Server: HTTP or HTTPS listener port is
>   occupied while server is not running

I have already tried to shutdown and remove Glassfish but it keeps printing the same message.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the answer

Choose your NetBeans project > properties > run > server > (select) Apache Tomcat or TomEE